# A white page appears when you press on 'Click here' on the bWAPP/install.php path

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A white page appears when you press 'Click here' on the bWAPP/install.php path

can anyone fix it plz?

I gave him all the permissions
and went through the installation details step by step A white page appears when entering /bWAPP/install.php?install=yes

Comment: A white page usually means an internal server error. Check your server error logs for more information

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/bWAPP/install.php:29\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/bWAPP/install.php on line 29, referer: http://localhost/bWAPP/install.php

Comment: i found it can you fix it for me plz